# PHP: Using ?.... after file.php

Tags: php

I have this:

```
pm.php?v=unread
```

Now in unread, you can filter too by pressing Messages or Invites, and the links look like this:

```
<a href="?f=msgs">Msgs</a> | <a href="?f=invites">Inv.</a>
```

If you are inside `pm.php?v=unread,` and press on Msgs, it will turn out as `pm.php?f=msgs`. 
And i wish it to be `pm.php?v=unread&f=msgs`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="?<?=($_GET['v']=="unread"?'v=unread&':'')?>f=msgs">Msgs</a>
```

or

```
<a href="?<?=($_GET['v']?'v='.$_GET['v'].'&':'')?>f=msgs">Msgs</a>
```

Comment: <?= is deprecated. use href="<?php echo ($_GET['v'] ? 'v=unread&' : ''); ?>f=msgs"

Comment: this will be a huge pain in the butt if you get a lot more items in your query string

Answer (score 5):

If you want to maintain *all* your $_GET vars and add an extra to your links, consider `array_merge()` and `http_build_query()`.

```
$gets=array_merge($_GET,array('f'=>'msgs'));//returns array with your new values overriding any old values
$getstring=http_build_query($gets);
$link="<a href="?$getstring>Msgs</a>";
```

Comment: this answer will help you in the long run

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="pm.php?f=msgs&v=<?php echo $_REQUEST['v']; ?>">Msgs</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to figure out all the get variables and add them to the URLs.
For example you could do something like this in your pm.php:

```
$params = ((isset($_GET['v'])?'v=' . $_GET['v']:'');
$params .= //do the same for all your expected variables
```

In the page you would do something like:

```
<a href="?f=msgs&<?php echo $params; ?">Msgs</a> | <a href="?f=invites&<?echo $params; ?>">Inv.</a>
```

This is obviously short and dirty. Assumes you will always have params, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun problem. Because what if you arent using any $_GET values, and you click messages? Then its going to go pm.php&f=msgs now here is my solution :)

```
function appendURL($name, $value) 
{ 
    // if we have a variable holding the '?' position
    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?')) 
    { 
        // append the value in the & position
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "&$name=$value"; 

    } 
    // otherwise, append it in the ? position
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "?$name=$value";
}
```

Now in your case

```
<a href="<?=appendURL('f', 'msgs')?>">Messages</a>
```

Haven't done this in a while, so don't crucify me if something is a little off! :)